# Sound plays through head phones but not speakers

Tags: sound

I have ubuntu 12.04, and the sound was working.

Now, when i try to listen to music nothing plays, Ubuntu is on my Dell latitude d620.

I am wondering why this is not working to play any songs through my speakers.

Answer (score 1):

On my system, the volume levels are set separately for headphones and for speakers. That is, when I connect the headphones the volume level changes.

Make sure it is not going to mute when you remove the headphones.

Comment: Can you explain *how* to make sure of this?

Comment: Simply increase the volume level as you normally do with the headphone unplugged.